# Field Returns a False or True -- not details

Tags: powershell, vsphere

After connecting to vSphere 6.7 from a win10 machine I run the following PowerShell command: Expecting the CSV output to include the details of Name, OperatingSystems (windows or linux), VMhost/IP, PowerState and the datastore.
However, in the field "Operating Systems" I get the value FALSE -or- TRUE. Still relatively new to PowerShell so I don't see my request asking for a false/true. How do I correct this? So I can change the commands from: OSWindows -to- OSLinux?
Thanks

```
 Get-VM | Select-Object Name, 
                           @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = {$_.Guest -match 'OsWindows'}},
                           VMHost, PowerState,
                           @{Name = 'Datastore'; Expression = {$_ | Get-Datastore}} |
             Export-CSV -Path 'C:\users\username\documents\VMReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You may simply remove the "Os" substring at the start of the string: `$_.Guest -replace '^Os'`

Answer (score 3):

`$_.Guest -match 'OsWindows'` will return a boolean (`$true` or `$false`).

If you want `$false` to result in the string `Linux` and `$true` to result in the string `Windows`, you can use the following trick:

```
@{...; Expression = {@('Linux','Windows')[($_.Guest -match 'OsWindows')]}}
```

PowerShell will evaluate `$_.Guest -match 'OsWindows'` - passing the resulting value to an array indexer `@()[...]` then forces PowerShell to convert it to a numerical value - and since it converts `$false` to `0` and `$true` to `1`, they end up resolving one of the two array items.

Comment: Ran the following: 
Get-VM | Select-Object Name, 
                       @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; @{...; Expression = {@('Linux','Windows')[($_.Guest -match 'OsWindows')]}},
                       VMHost, PowerState,
                       @{Name = 'Datastore'; Expression = {$_ | Get-Datastore}} |
      Export-CSV -Path 'C:\users\username\documents\VMReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Error: 
At line:2 char:53
+                        @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; @{...; Expression  ...
+                                                     ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:2 char:53
+                        @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; @{...; Expression  ...
+                                                     ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteHashLiteral

Comment: Hmmm, forget to switch out part of the sequence... I got it...
Get-VM | Select-Object Name, 
                       @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = {@('Linux','Windows')[($_.Guest -match 'OsWindows')]}},
                       VMHost, PowerState,
                       @{Name = 'Datastore'; Expression = {$_ | Get-Datastore}} |
      Export-CSV -Path 'C:\users\username\documents\VMReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @Rbuckle The error quite clearly says you ran it with `...` still in the code

Comment: I corrected that and added in the
Get-VM | Select-Object Name, 
                       @{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = {@('Linux','Windows')[($_.Guest -match 'OsWindows')]}},
                       VMHost, PowerState,
                       @{Name = 'Datastore'; Expression = {$_ | Get-Datastore}} |
      Export-CSV -Path 'C:\users\username\documents\VMReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @Rbuckle If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: Thank You. 
Question: The scripts work for inputting the word 'Linux' and 'Windows' into the field when I flip the script:  
@{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = {@('Linux','Windows')[($_.Guest -match 'OsWindows')]}},
However, the field is merely being just filled with the Verbiage: 'Linux' 'Windows'. I don't see that it is actually pulling the data, as there is no difference in the names on list. It merely says NAME: "2012migrate" OPERATINGSYSTEM: "windows" It is does not reflect the actually OS version such as Server 2016 -or- Ubuntu. 
I have a lot to learn, yes.

Comment: @Rbuckle Is `$_.Guest` a string? If so, simply do `@{Name = 'Operatingsystem'; Expression = 'Guest'}` to rename the property

Comment: Finally figured the sequence out.. Now to see if I can get the Listing of the Guest OS Column showing the Windows OS, then Showing the Linux OS. As the previous scripts did not retrieve the total of all the Operating Systems in vSphere. 

Get-VM | Select @{Label = "VM Name" ; Expression = {$_.Name} },VMHost, PowerState, @{Label = "Guest OS" ; Expression = {$_.ExtensionData.Config.GuestFullName} }| Export-CSV -Path 'C:\users\username\documents\VMPowerOS.csv' -NoTypeInformation –